# JavaScript live clock is not running

Tags: javascript, php, clock, live

php splits variable problem while passing in javascript or there is problem with the logic of runing live clock , any help will be appreciated, guide me where am i wrong ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function show(){
    var hours= '<?php echo $splits[0];?>';
    var minutes= '<?php echo $splits[1];?>';
    var seconds= '<?php echo $splits[2];?>';
    var dn="AM" 
    if (hours>12){
        dn="PM"
        hours=hours-12
        //this is so the hours written out is in 12-hour format, instead of the default //24-hour format.
    }
    if (hours==0)
        hours=12
    //this is so the hours written out when hours=0 (meaning 12a.m) is 12
    if (minutes<=9)
        minutes="0"+minutes
    if (seconds<=9)
        seconds="0"+seconds
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=
    hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+" "+dn
    setTimeout("show()",1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="show()">
<?php
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata') );
$duration = $date->format("H:i:s");
$splits =  explode(":",$duration);
settype($splits[0], "integer");
settype($splits[1], "integer");
settype($splits[2], "integer"); 
?>
<p id="demo"></p>
<h1 id="demo1"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't define `$splits`  early enough. PHP is procedural in your approach so everything must be defined before usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use vanilla JavaScript:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function show(){
    var timer = new Date().
      toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' })
      .split(',')[1]
      .trim();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timer
    setTimeout("show()",1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="show()">
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if someone wants to do the same using latitude and longitude, how we can do so?. latitude and longitude is known to us

Comment: I recommend you to post new question about this. Some thing like "How get timezone by latitude and longitude"